Christian movie about woman who leaves her family
It's about a woman who leaves her husband and kid due to unspecified reasons, but meets them in a religious camp for kid after 10 years. It is a christian movie.
Could you tell me the name of the movie?

Could you add more details? When was it released, or at least when did you see it? Was it an English speaking film? American? Any other details you can remember?

It is an American made for TV movie. Not a major star cast but a very beautiful movie. It is adopted by the Christan community as a religious movie. Just can't seem to get the name.

After much searching got it:
No Greater Love (2010)

No Greater Love is a 2010 Christian film directed by Brad J. Silverman. 

